# A column named ColumnOrdinal already belongs to the data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

Sometimes my code catches below exception but I am unable to find the reason. It happens randomly and if I make a second call to the API, the error goes away and data is fetched fine.

> System.Data.DuplicateNameException: 'A column named 'ColumnOrdinal' already belongs to this DataTable.'

Below is the code sample. Is there something which is causing repetitiveness? Also, I searched whole code but there is no column with the name ColumnOrdinal in the whole solution.

```
public static List<Users> GetUsersList()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> allUsers = null;
        DataTable dtResult = Data.GetUserList();
        if (dtResult != null)
        {
            allUsers = new List<Users>(dtResult.Rows.Count);
            Users oneUser;

            foreach (DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
            {
                oneUser = new Users()
                {
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(row["USER_ID"]),
                    userName = Convert.ToString(row["USER_NAME"]),                          

                };
                allUsers.Add(oneUser);
            };
        }
        return allUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this method on multiple threads?  Could be stepping on your own tows.

Comment: The issue is with it being a static List<Users>.  As the other commentator indicated, you are stepping on your own toes as it tries to the add to the same data table.  This might help give yo some insight https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1202280/A-column-named-client-meeting-ID-already-belongs-t

Comment: Check the orders of your columns. Also, is the comma after the userName necessary?

Comment: Ok. The method is not called on multiple threads but I can check the Static List change.